# How to move columns of a data frame into rows after the first few columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with each row representing a sequence of schools

```
edu <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Elem Mid High
e1 m1 h1
e2 m2 h2
e1 m2 h2
e3 m1 h1")
```

I'd like to transform this into a edge list

```
  s1 s2
1 e1 m1
2 e2 m2
3 e1 m2
4 e3 m1
5 m1 h1
6 m2 h2
7 m2 h2
8 m1 h1
```

for a directed graph (via the igraph package).

Here's how I do it:

```
e2m <- edu[,1:2]
m2h <- edu[,2:3]
colnames(e2m) <- c("s1", "s2")
colnames(m2h) <- c("s1", "s2")
schools <- rbind(e2m,m2e)
```

"schools" contains what I want, but it is iterative and becomes cumbersome if I want to add a fourth column (e.g. "Uni"). What is the vectorized way to do this?

Comment: Can I say this is a great question in that you (1) `asked a question`, (2) `provide a small working data set`, (3) `show desired output` and (4) `what you're currently doing.` +1

Comment: I'm woefully unskilled in its use, but isn't this what `melt` -- `recast` does?

Comment: @Carl, I thought the same as well, but it's not the case, at least not straightforward. Note that the first column of the transformed `data.frame` has both the first column and second column from `edu`.

Comment: @Arun : thanks.  Save me the trouble of trying to code it up.

Comment: @Carl, melt|recast|merge was my thought as well and I did try to code it up, which ended in tears...

All: thanks for the inputs. I tried them all with a 'Uni'-fied dataframe and they all worked great. I don't know which one to pick...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
len <- seq_along(edu)
a <- head(len, -1)
b <- tail(len, -1)

data.frame(s1=as.character(unlist(edu[, a])), s2=as.character(unlist(edu[, b])))
```

Comment: The first two aren't quite right (too many combinations are printed).  "Edit2" is correct and awesome.

Answer (score 6):

Directly translating the OP's code into an apply.  This isn't vectorized:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(ncol(edu)-1), FUN=function(x){
  r <- edu[,x:(x+1)]
  colnames(r) <- c('s1', 's2')
  r
}

))
```

Answer (score 3):

Working off of @Tyler's Method:

```
# assuming a new column added
edu$Uni <- as.factor(c("u1", "u2", "u1", "u1"))
```

.

```
rows  <- nrow(edu)
total <- prod(dim(edu))  # ie: nrow(edu) * ncol(edu)  

X <- as.character(unlist(edu))
data.frame(s1=X[1:(total-rows)],  s2=X[(rows+1):total])
```

Results:

```
   s1 s2
1  e1 m1
2  e2 m2
3  e1 m2
4  e3 m1
5  m1 h1
6  m2 h2
7  m2 h2
8  m1 h1
9  h1 u1  <~~~ Added "Uni" column
10 h2 u2  <~~~ Added "Uni" column
11 h2 u1  <~~~ Added "Uni" column
12 h1 u1  <~~~ Added "Uni" column
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with a matrix output, as accepted by the `igraph` functions.

```
t(
  matrix(
   apply(edu,1,function(x) x[c(1,rep(2:(length(x)-1),each=2),length(x))]),
   nrow=2
        )
 )
```

Result:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "e1" "m1"
[2,] "m1" "h1"
[3,] "e2" "m2"
[4,] "m2" "h2"
[5,] "e1" "m2"
[6,] "m2" "h2"
[7,] "e3" "m1"
[8,] "m1" "h1"
```

And convert to a graph:

```
> graph.edgelist(result)
IGRAPH DN-- 7 8 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
```